# Terrain profile error

Tags: qgis-plugins, terrain-tools

I am using QGIS 2.4.0 Chugiak and am trying to create an elevation profile from a raster. When I click on the terrain profile icon I get an error message (see below).

Has these problem been encountered before and does anybody know an easy solution to this problem?

An error has occured while executing Python code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:/Users/eesje/.qgis2/python/plugins\profiletool\profileplugin.py",
> line 299, in changePlotLibrary
> self.wdg.addPlotWidget(self.plotlibrary)   File "C:/Users/eesje/.qgis2/python/plugins\profiletool\ui\ptdockwidget.py",
> line 145, in addPlotWidget
> self.plotWdg = PlottingTool().changePlotWidget("Matplotlib", self.frame_for_plot)   File
> "C:/Users/eesje/.qgis2/python/plugins\profiletool\tools\plottingtool.py",
> line 82, in changePlotWidget
> from matplotlib.figure import Figure   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in
> _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 34, in
> import matplotlib.colorbar as cbar   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in
> _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py",
> line 29, in
> import matplotlib.collections as collections   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in
> _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py",
> line 23, in
> import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in
> _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py",
> line 50, in
> import matplotlib.textpath as textpath   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in
> _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py",
> line 11, in
> import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager   File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in
> _import
> mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)   File
> "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py",
> line 1356, in
> _rebuild()   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py",
> line 1341, in _rebuild
> fontManager = FontManager()   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py",
> line 1004, in **init**
> self.ttflist = createFontList(self.ttffiles)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py",
> line 584, in createFontList
> prop = ttfFontProperty(font)   File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISCH~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py",
> line 398, in ttfFontProperty
> sfnt4 = sfnt4.decode('ascii').lower() UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>
> Python version:
> 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: The QGIS 2.4.0 that you have is indeed a very old version of QGIS and Terrain profile was updated many times since QGIS 2.4.0. Try to update your QGIS to the current long term release of 2.18.19 (LTR) and use terrain profile. It may solve the problem.